# Enabling And Disabling Buttons In GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview, button

I have added a button column to a gridview. I am populating the gridview with a datable through code then binding the datable to the grid.

I need to now look at the first column of the data and check if the text of the column is "NA" if it is the button in that column has to be disabled.....

How can I accomplish this? I am populating the data from code and the button is preadded to the grid in the markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonField Text="Delete" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>


GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best thing to do is implement the `OnDataBinding` method for a `Button` in a `TemplateColumn`.

Eg:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDelete" CommandName="Delete" 
                    Text="Delete" OnDataBinding="btnDelete_DataBinding" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then in your codebehind implement your logic:

```
protected void btnDelete_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)(sender);
    btn.Enabled = !Eval("TheFieldInYourDataSourceToCompare").ToString().Equals("NA");
}
```

The advantage to doing it in this manner over the other posted answers:

1. No code in your markup
2. Code is localized to the `Button` control and can be reused if other `Buttons` require the same functionality.
3. Comparing to the `DataSource` value and not what the visual output is (this could tie into business logic for both rendering and checking).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just a note the the above C# has a syntax error ...missing () after toString

Comment: @mickey Thanks. Old post but I fixed it :)  Hope it was helpful.

Comment: I tried to implement as Kelsey suggests, but I have a *DataGrid* instead of a *GridView*. I get this run-time error:
*Parser Error Message: System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridColumnCollection must have items of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridColumn'. 'asp:TemplateField' is of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TemplateField'.*, so I think I must use <asp:TemplateColumn> instead

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the DataBound event handler:

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        if (GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text == "NA")
        {
          // Disable the button
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a general idea.  You'll have to modify the code for your application.

Don't forget to add `OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound"` to the markup for the GridView.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this.
Did the button a little differently

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Btn_Delete" CommandName="Delete" Text="delete" 
                    Enabled='<%# GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text != "NA" %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

You'll want to you Eval("someColumn") most likely instead of GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text

Comment: Good alternative.  One thing to point out though - you've hardcoded Rows[0].  You'll probably want to base the enable/disable on the corresponding row, not the first row every time :)

Comment: Yeah, definitely. I did that since Nick didn't provide us with the full code.

Comment: So Eval("DatabaseColumn") would probably work depending on the situation I guess

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use  OnRowDataBound="GridViewRowEventHandler" to set the value to enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 0):

you can try from markup as,

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QA signature">
                                     <EditItemTemplate>
                                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Column6") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                     </EditItemTemplate>
                                     <ItemTemplate>
                                         <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Column6") %>' Visible='<%# Eval("Column6") != "" %>'  ></asp:Label>
                                         <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Sign Off" CssClass="cmdButton" Visible='<%# Eval("Column6") == "" %>'  />
                                     </ItemTemplate>
                                 </asp:TemplateField>
```